# Updating plot with values received from TCP connection python

Tags: python, dynamic, plot, winsock2

I would like to ask if it is possible to update/draw the plot in python dynamically. My program suppose to capture the data from IMU sensor- this is done in c++ (client). In python I am receiving captured data (server). And now I would like to represent these data graphically. The connection works fine Iam getting the data sent from c++.I tried to play with the code but it does not work mainly because I am calling plt.show() forever. Is this possible ?? This is my code

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT=1024
BUFFSIZE=1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpTimeSrvrSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
tcpTimeSrvrSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpTimeSrvrSock.listen(50)

while True:

    print 'waiting for connction'
    tcpTimeClientSock, addr = tcpTimeSrvrSock.accept()
    print 'connected from:', addr

    while True:
        data =tcpTimeClientSock.recv (BUFFSIZE)
    if not data:
        print 'no data'
        break


    x =float(data[0 : data.find('?')])//data received from client c++
    data=data[data.find('?')+1:]
    y=float(data[0 : data.find('£')])
    data=data[data.find('£')+1:]
    z=float(data[0 : data.find('$')])
    data=data[data.find('$')+1:]
    frame=int(data[0 : data.find('#')])


    #print data
    #print x
    #print y
    #print z
    #print frame

    tcpTimeClientSock.send('[%s] %s' % (ctime(), data))
    plt.plot(frame,x,'r')
    plt.plot(frame,y,'b')
    plt.plot(frame,z,'g')

    plt.show()


tcpTimeClientSock.close()


tcpTimeSrvrSock.close()
```

Thank you